# How can I set onPress event in a child component?

Tags: react-native

I have a file called SplashScreen.js with a StackNavigator. Sample code:

[image]

Inside my SplashScreen.js I have a component called "Login" and INSIDE Login I have a component called "TouchbleOpacity"

[image]

What I need is to change the "onPress" event of my TouchbleOpacity component. So I'll be able to navigate in my Navigator (that are inside my SplashScreen.js). The onPress event should look similar to this: `onPress={() => navigation.navigate('TelaCadastrar01')`

If there is a better way to change the onPress event of my TouchbleOpacity, please tell me, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but i'll give it a try:

In your Login Component you do:

```
//first button
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress} >
    <Text> ... </Text>
</TouchableOpacity> 

//second button 
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPressButton2} >
    <Text> ... </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Now you are able to pass any onPress function to your Login Component. e.g.

```
<Login onPress={() => navigation.navigate('TelaCadastrar01')} onPressButton2={() => console.log('second scene')}/>
```

Comment: Wow man worked!!! One more thing, Inside my "Login" I have two buttons, one is the Login button and the other is the Sign In button. Each button go to different screens. How can I manage this situation? How can I know wich button was pressed?

Comment: @DiegoBittencourt you're welcome!  I edited my answer to handle a second button. Please accept and/or vote up my answer :) Thank you

Comment: @TimH here you have shown how to navigate or console, how can i call a function here, where we should define it?

Comment: @Anjana-Systematix you should define the function in the component, which is calling your sub component.  And to actually call it you could do:  <Login onPress={() => this.YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME()} />